# Meaning of Negative time in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity

Consider the following situation, let $S$ and $R$ be two inertial reference frames. Assume that $R$ moves with a velocity $v$ in the $x$-direction w.r.t $S$. For simplicity consider a two dimensional space-time $(x,t)$ where we set $c=1$. Also $S$ and $R$ meet and synchronize their clocks at $(0,0)$.

Suppose an event $E$ occurs in $S$ with co-ordinate $(1,0)$.

The coordinate of the same event in $R$ frame would be,$(\gamma,-\beta \gamma)$.

So in $R$ the event $E$ happened with a negative time co-ordinate.

My questions are,

- We know that $R$ and $S$ meet at $(0,0)$ and synchronize their clocks at this point, so does it make sense to talk about this event which happens with a negative time co-ordinate in $R$ frame as we do not know about the configurations of the respective clocks before $(0,0)$?
- What does this negative time mean physically?
- Is this answer obtained by Lorentz transformation equation correct, as we do not know the configurations of the clock before $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1):

An event with a negative time coordinate happened before the definition of t=0 in that coordinate system. It is really not any different from comparing 2017 BC with 2017 AD. Physics-wise, there is nothing special about 0. Merry Christmas.

Comment: Yes agreed. But is the answer given by the transformation equation right? We do not know the configurations before $t=0$ of the clocks.

Comment: @Abhikumbale, why?  Typically, in these kinds of problems, it is simply stipulated that at the event that the spatial origins are co-located, it just is the case that $t = t' = 0$, and not that any synchronization procedure is done at that event.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Agreed if you view it that way. But there is a possibility that such a synchronization could have happened isn't there? How can you explain the situation then?

Comment: @Abhikumbale wrote *"Agreed if you view it that way."* - I know now that there's no value to be gained in going any further with this.

Comment: A zero time coordinate has no physical meaning different from, say t=42. For instance, the 1st moon landing occurred at negative UNIX time: so what.

Comment: @JEB look at my third question please.